# Converting Multiple string inputs to int

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm trying to convert `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` to integers, but after I've tried doing this they still come up as strings. I've tried using a loop instead of `map`, but that didn't work either.

```
inputs = input()
split_input = inputs.split()
a, b, c, d = split_input
split_input = list(map(int, split_input))
```

Comment: Your `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` variables are assigned the result of splatting the `split_input` array, which is an array of strings at the moment when this assignment is happening. Move your map operation to happen first, so that you assign from the result of *that* instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just swap the last 2 lines:

```
split_input = list(map(int, split_input))
a, b, c, d = split_input
```

Unless you need `split_input` later on, you don't need the list conversion at all:

```
split_input = map(int, split_input)
a, b, c, d = split_input
# OR in fact simply
a, b, c, d = map(int, split_input)
```