# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3' in python

Tags: python

For the given code, when I enter 1 2 3 as input, its throwing Value Error, please guide.

```
def Solve (MAT):
    
    # Write your code here
    res=[]
    if(len(MAT)==0):
        return res
    m=len(MAT)
    n=len(MAT)
    found=[[0 for i in range(n)]for j in range(m)]
    dr=[0,1,0,-1]
    dc=[1,0,-1,0]
    x=0
    y=0
    di=0
    for i in range(m*n):
        res.append(MAT[x][y])
        found[x][y]=True
        cr=x+dr[di]
        cc=y+dc[di]
        if(0<=cr and cr<m and 0<=cc and cc<n and not(found[cr][cc])):
            x=cr
            y=cc
        else:
            di=(di+1)%4
            x+=dr[di]
            y+=dc[di]

    return res
```

After this am getting the value error. For input am giving 1 2 3 integers but its throwing value error. The main program code for the same is given below

```
N = int(input())
M = int(input())
MAT = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(N)]

out_ = Solve(MAT)
for i in out_:
    print (' '.join(map(str, i)))
```

Comment: Your program expects one single integer on the first line.

Comment: You're supposed to enter single numbers for the first two numbers, and then enter `1 2 3` as the *third* input.  It might be more clear if you added prompts to your `input()` calls so you know what you're supposed to be entering each time.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Even if I enter 1 number at a time, am getting an error saying-    print (' '.join(map(str, i_out_)))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Multiple string inputs to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826296/converting-multiple-string-inputs-to-int)